# Installing and using Google's PHP library for OAuth 2

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

In order to post/upload some stuff from my local php script (running on my machine) to a (my) GAE app, I am doing this:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation

I installed that library locally in the same folder where I use my uploading php script, using composer. The installation works fine, but I just don't understand what I need to do to be able to use the Google_Client() class etc in my script. The "Setting include_path dynamically in your code" does not really help and the steps to include that library properly seems to be missing.

Some background info:
I used to be able to upload/post fine to my GAE app by getting "sacsid" cookies, until any of these reasons:

- I enabled two-step verification on the account that I used to access the admin of the GAE app
- Google deprecated that "sacsid" process.

I might very well be wrong about that stuff but I guess the official way these days is to use said php library for this right?

Specifically I tried this at the top  of my script:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

And I get

> Fatal error: Class
>   'google\appengine\api\app_identity\AppIdentityService' not found in
>   /vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Auth/AppIdentity.php on line 79

Comment: If you're using composer, you shouldn't need to change include_path at all. ``require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'`` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The class mentioned above is defined in the [AppEngine PHP SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk), which is pulled in automatically when your code runs on AppEngine. It authenticates your AppEngine application with the Google APIs.

For local development, you will need to authenticate a different way. The best method is by using [Service Account Credentials](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#authorizingrequests). I recommend upgrading to the latest version (`v2`) of the client library, where this is [handled automatically](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_appidentity-has-been-removed).

Comment: Hi, I just got back to look at this. And am having some trouble getting this to work. You got some concrete sample code how to authenticate a request to a GAE app? I find it hard to find any docs at Google that are to the point of that.

Comment: Hi Jonny. By "to a GAE app" what exactly are you trying to authenticate for? This library is used for making calls to Google APIs, not to apps running on Google App Engine.

Comment: I have an API I created myself at someapp.appspot.com/myapi - it needs admin authentication in order not to make that public. I'll use it to POST some data from another server periodically.

Comment: I had a working way of logging my script in as admin by using "sacsid" cookies - see the paragraph in my post above. I need something that does the same job again.

Comment: Try adding 'use google\appengine\api\app_identity\AppIdentityService;'